# Tool with GUI used to detect segfault in mixed C and Fortran code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fortran

I am working with C code functions that call legacy Fortran code subroutines.  The Fortran code subroutines also call other C code functions.  The code that I am working with is not the prettiest, but it is fairly challenging to re-write everything from scratch.

Unfortunately, a segfault is occurring somewhere within the program, and I am wondering if there is a software tool with a nice GUI that can be used to accurately pinpoint the location in both C and Fortran code.

Although I am developing the software program on Windows using the Open Watcom compiler to compile both C and Fortran code, I'm willing to move the code to my GNU/Linux box if there is a FOSS tool that can be used.

Alternately, I would wonder if the Intel Composer XE suite could be used to visually pinpoint the location of the segmentation violation.  The Intel Composer XE suite includes both C and Fortran compilers.

Since I am working with C and Fortran code, I need some sort of indication where in the code the segfault is occurring.  I don't especially want to use calls to the `printf()` function.

Comment: On Linux the GNU debugger `gdb` is king and it (kind of) supports mixed language binaries. There are GUI wrappers around it like `DDD`, as well as many commercial tools. The (still free) Oracle Solaris Studio offers a fully integrated IDE solution on Linux which also provides GUI wrapping around `gdb`.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Thanks, Hristo.  I will check out Solaris Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a GUI, but [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is an excellent memory debugging tool. It will tell you not just which line a segfault is on (which you should be able to do with any debugger), but also each time you access uninitialized or unallocated memory, or make a variety of other errors. You do need to port to Linux to use it though.

Comment: Thanks, Jamey.  I think that valgrind does have a few GUIs available for it, so I'm happy with using this software. Can valgrind pinpoint the location of the segfault in mixed C and Fortran code?  Can an ordinary debugger also do this as well, or is valgrind something special in this regard?

Comment: I don't know about any commercial debuggers, and I haven't personally debugged Fortran code--but `gdb` will automatically switch languages between C, C++, Fortran, assembly, Ada, and lots of others. Since `valgrind` just looks at debug symbols, I assume it can handle anything that GCC can compile as well, including Fortran. So I'd expect both to work for you.

Comment: Thanks, Jamey.  I'll try `gdb` and `valgrind`.  It is good to know that these two tools will automatically switch between languages.

Comment: IMHO, `gdb` is very useful; even if it is text-based, the program still gives much useful debugging output.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio integration provided with the Intel Visual Fortran product on Windows allows GUI debugging of mixed Fortran and C code.

On Linux Intel ship their own GUI based debugging environment (idb) with their compiler products.

Comment: Thanks, Ian; it is great to know that Intel Visual Fortran allows GUI debugging of mixed Fortran and C.

Comment: This is a good solution as well; thank you!  There is also information showing how to build mixed language solutions in Visual Studio using the Intel compilers: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-compiler-for-windows-building-mixed-language-applications-under-visual-studio.